# alerts appear after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
 <%= link_to "Delete",(@article) ,method:"delete",data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete ?' } %>
```

I have a rails app which lets the user create an account, post, delete and update comments, and get notifications using rails and Jquery.

When I click the buttons which include confirm messages do not work until I refresh the page. Why ? What should I do ?

after removing the `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>` from the application,It saves the updates directly without alerting useres

Comment: you may forget to end some html elements like `div` check it out

Comment: What does your controller look like?

Comment: @pitabas prathal Thank you  it was **</div>**

Comment: Thank you for you all Graham Slick & Antarr Byrd

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete',url_for(action: :delete,id: @article.id),method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
```

Comment: it is ok Thank you  ruby_newbie